# Calculate annual leave between two dates in Excel

Tags: excel, date

This task seems easy enough yet I just can't figure a way of doing this without resorting to vba.

All I need is to know the number of hours an employee has used up on annual leave, based on a start and end date, and their hours of work.

[image: Hours of Work]

To be more clear, this example shows one employees contracted hours from Monday to Sunday i.e. they work only Weds, Thurs, and Friday, for 7.5 hours each day.
Below shows the start and end date that the employee has chosen to take for annual leave. I need to calculate, based on their contracted hours, how much annual leave is used between the two dates. The answer would be 45 hours in this case.

Comment: You'll have to include a bit more details for us to help you: (1) what are the hours a person is required to work per day, (2) which days of the week is the person assumed to work, (3) how about holidays and vacations, (4) which format is the given data for a longer period (for example 10/04/2017 through 22/10/2017)? Do you have in this case almost 200 columns next to each other? Wouldn't it be easier to keep the data in rows? Also, I cannot see any dates attached to the weekdays or are you just hiding this information under the formatting and `Mon` actually contains the date?

Comment: Employees all could have various hours of work to others. My question gives an example of one employee who works 7.5 hours Wednesday, Thursday, and Friday. This is their contracted hours for the year. The dates I've provided are the start and end to annual leave the employee has wished to take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another approach - I've expanded the days between the start and end dates into an array then used the resulting day numbers to offset into the days of work range

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(A3,0,WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(A6&":"&B6)),2)-1)))
```

[image]

If you had a list of holiday dates somewhere (say in I3:N3) you could exclude them as follows

```
=SUMPRODUCT(N(OFFSET(A3,0,WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(A6&":"&B6)),2)-1))*ISNA(MATCH(ROW(INDIRECT(A6&":"&B6)),I3:N3,0)))
```

- it is a bit long-winded but the only way I can think of at the moment.

Comment: Beat me with that algorithm by less than a minute

Comment: This is an excellent and eloquent solution. It stands up to my own results when using =networkdays.intl counting each day across seven cells as a holiday and then summing it all together. This is much cleaner and nicer to use.

Comment: I'm not usually noted for speed but luckily it worked without too much faffing around

Comment: As a follow up question, would you know how to avoid counting for bank holidays? I could make a new post for that if you'd prefer?

Comment: I can't find a very elegant way of doing it but can add a possible way to my answer.

Comment: Works brilliantly. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can the above be done using something like index rather than offset? Offset can really slow down excel when there is too many of them in one workbook.

Comment: The short answer is no, because you can't pass an array of lookup values to INDEX like you can with OFFSET. It would be possible to use LOOKUP but I don't think it would be any quicker because it's doing a lookup rather than going directly to a particular cell based on a value.

Comment: Thanks again for your response. You've been extremely helpful.